# Do we need to use Sleuth with Zipkin

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

In order to trace service invocation across microservices , we can use Zipkin.

From the below URLs ,we understand the time taken for calls across micro services can be captured in zipkin

https://tanzu.vmware.com/developer/guides/spring/spring-zipkin/

https://springhow.com/spring-boot-zipkin-distributed-tracing/

Do we still need to use spring sleuth along with zipkin ? Does the span id and trace id generated by Sletuh provide any additional information apart from what Zipkin can capture on its own ?

Comment: Sleuth auto configures instrumentation for spring boot apps from brave (a zipkin library) which can then send traces to zipkin

Comment: Thanks . Since brave is a zipkin library i presume there is no need to have dependency on sleuth in order to trace service calls across microservices.

I believe one probable benefit of Sleuth is that it adds the span id and trace id in the application logs ( using logback MDC concept ) . These logs can be pushed into elastic search using Logstash.

Answer (score 1):

Since brave is a zipkin library I presume there is no need to have dependency on sleuth in order to trace service calls across microservices.

One probable benefit of Sleuth is that it adds the span id and trace id in the application logs ( using logback MDC concept ) . These logs can be pushed into elastic search using Logstash

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only Spring Cloud Sleuth without the Zipkin integration, add the spring-cloud-starter-sleuth module to your project

[Check this for reference](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/reference/html/#only-sleuth-log-correlation)